# How to generate Java Docs in Android ADT bundle

Tags: java, android, javadoc, eclipse-adt

I'm trying to create Java Docs for my Android application from the Eclipse ADT bundle for Android, but when I go to Project --> Generate Java Docs.. and add the path of the java doc tool: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\javadoc.exe` the docs folder is empty and I get the following error output:

http://hastebin.com/iqicagaxiy.tex

I researched the question and came tried the following solution to no avail:

Add the Android Java Doc tool, in `C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\docs\reference` which I got from the by expanding the Android folder in the project's build path.

But this throws an error when I try to specify as a build path: `The command does not exist` which suggests the java doc tool is not present in the folder.

Anyone have any advice on generating the Java Docs using the ADT bundle?
Am I missing a step somewhere in configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the Java doc tool directly from the command line, instead of through the Eclipse GUI:

`javadoc -d "output directory" -sourcepath "project path" -subpackages ''package name`